# Unable to ignore a directory in WordPress install via .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

```
/custom/player-registration.php
```

I've used the following .htaccess in my WordPress install and I can't access the above URL... any tips?  I've tried 2 methods here...  The URL continues to go to a WordPress search page.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^custom - [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(custom|custom/.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**UPDATE**

I suppose I need to clarify that I am able to access /custom but am NOT able to access files within that directory... how do I access files within that directory?

Answer (score 0):

Default WP .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

means: if request doesn't point to any existing file or directory, use index.php

So it should serve Your file well with default settings. What are You trying to acomplish with the rest of Your file?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^custom.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```